# Nikon D5300 Location Data?

Tags: troubleshooting, nikon-d5300

I've recently bought the Nikon D5300 and everything seems fine apart from the GPS / Location Data. I bought it via 'Amazon.co.uk' > KCS Electronics.

Basically the GPS flashes but I have not been able to get any lock at all, where the 1 to 3 strength indicators come on.

I also successfully updated the A-GPS.ee file, but this has made no difference at all.

KCS are being very upfront and after requesting my serial number to check, said it is a European number, as I have heard that some Chinese models have GPS blocked. They have said it maybe faulty and without question have offered a replacement or refund. The thing is I just want to be sure it isn't me. Must admit I have not tried it in an open space, but searching on Google it does seem to be a bit hit or miss function on the D5300.

ANy thought would be appreciated?

Keith

Comment: Before going further will be wise to check go outside, switch on the camera and GPS and wait at least 10 minutes. Then you can try to take some photos and check if they have location in EXIF. GPS is not reliable indoor.

Comment: I will do that. After a few seconds the camera screen switches off, does this matter? Do I just leave the 'on/off' switch to 'on'

Comment: LCD screen is not so important. But you should keep camera active (like taking one photo every minute). Or at least halfpress the shutter button. This IMHO will prevent camera from going in sleep mode.

Comment: Eureka :-) I am inside, pouring with rain outside and dark, but left it on and I have 3 dots and it's static. Thank you for hanging in there with me.

Answer (score 1):

Before going further will be wise to check and go outside. Then switch on the camera and GPS and wait at least 10 minutes. Then you can try to take some photos and check if they have location in EXIF. GPS is not reliable indoor.

Also is important to keep camera active by taking photo every minute for example or half pressing the shutter button.